# What to do with egg whites after stiff peaks collapse & you can't re-beat

Tags: egg-whites, meringue

So weird situation... beat eggs to stiff peaks with intention of making meringues. Forgot about them somehow (dinner party), but now, my friend's mixer that we borrowed is no longer available and the peaks have collapsed... anything else I can do with them? They already have sugar and vanilla and cream of tartar

Comment: Without the sugar and vanilla and cream of tartar, what you'd have would be called "glair", and you could use it for binding pigments (in other words, making paint). As it is, I'm not sure there's much you can do. I severely doubt if you can re-whip the eggs, but I've never tried that, hence comment, not answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making coconut macaroons: http://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1012523-coconut-nut-macaroons

The egg whites only have to be lightly beaten until they're foamy, so deflated egg whites might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a whisk which is the old fashioned way, but expect to get some excerise.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - or maybe I did? I read it as his egg whites being ruined already for the purpose of meringue, and he asking how to use them up instead of throwing them out. A whisk may prevent overwhipping with the next batch, but that's beside the point.

Comment: I read it as, he just doesn't have an electric beater.

Comment: Alas I don't have a whisk either....

Comment: You could also use just a fork, which is even more exercise. I'm also curious whether re-whipping would work, though.